# Aggregate strings from two columns in two different tables JOINed in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

Here's how my tables exist in the postgres db -

Student

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Roger |
| 2 | Roman |

School

| Id | Name | Address_Id | Student_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | School1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | School2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | School3 | 3 | 2 |

College

| Id | Name | Address_Id | Student_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | College1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | College2 | 3 | 2 |

Address

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Brooklyn |
| 2 | Manhattan |
| 3 | Troy |

I want a SQL query to get the student id, student name and places where they have been in the course of school and college life.

| ID | Student Name | Visited Places |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roger | Brooklyn, Manhattan |
| 2 | Roman | Troy |

I tried something like this but it didn't work -

```
SELECT 
   s.Id AS 'ID', 
   s.Name AS 'Student Name',
   STRING_AGG(a.Name, ', ')AS 'Visited Places'
FROM Student s
   LEFT JOIN School sc ON sc.Student_Id = s.Id
   LEFT JOIN Address a ON a.Id = sc.Address_Id
   LEFT JOIN College c ON c.Student_Id = s.Id
   LEFT JOIN Address a ON a.Id = c.Address_Id;
```

Comment: hmm I don't see a reason why you need to join on `College` at all

Comment: @richyen, for the OP's sample data, the results would be the same whether or not `College` was included in the joins; however, had a student visited a college with an address that wasn't associated with any of the schools that the student had visited, then the results would differ if `College` was not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The following query first determines all of the unique student and address pairs. The main part of the query uses these to join between students and addresses.

```
WITH
  visited_addresses AS (
    SELECT student_id, address_id
      FROM School
    UNION
    SELECT student_id, address_id
      FROM College
  )
SELECT s.id AS "ID",
       s.name AS "Student Name",
       string_agg(a.name, ', ' ORDER BY a.name) AS "Visited Places"
  FROM Student s
  LEFT JOIN visited_addresses v
    ON s.id = v.student_id
  LEFT JOIN Address a
    ON v.address_id = a.id
 GROUP BY s.id, s.name
 ORDER BY s.id;
```

This next query returns the same results, but uses a lateral join to get the visited addresses for each student:

```
SELECT s.id AS "ID",
       s.name AS "Student Name",
       string_agg(a.name, ', ' ORDER BY a.name)
  FROM Student s
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT sc.address_id
                        FROM School sc
                       WHERE sc.student_id = s.id
                      UNION
                      SELECT c.address_id
                        FROM College c
                       WHERE c.student_id = s.id
                     ) v
    ON TRUE
  LEFT JOIN Address a
    ON v.address_id = a.id
 GROUP BY s.id, s.name
 ORDER BY s.id;
```